# Can I display cell running time in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have this installed: https://github.com/deshaw/jupyterlab-execute-time
While the cell runs it displays `Execution started at 2022-09-20 16:57:19`

So you can calculate how long the cell is running by looking at the wall clock.

However its not exactly convenient especially if run time is hours.

Is there a plugin for JupyterLab which displays actual running time once a second for example or even minute would be nice?

Or share an idea how to implement it in a custom plugin..

Comment: Here is an idea (this will not work on per-cell basis, but if you execute only one cell then it kinda works): in recent versions you can hover over the busy indicator (the dark circle next to kernel name) and it will show you the time elapsed since starting the execution queue.

Comment: yeah I saw it. but i have dozens of cells so again i need to calculate and keep in mind how long took previous ones etc.. too much bother